# rails with ajax param url: nested routes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, handsontable

I tried to find a solution but no problem looks like mine.

I have a nested resource "students" :

```
  resources :grades do
    resources :students
  end
```

Added : Controller code

students_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_grade

 def set_grade
    @grade = Grade.find(params[:grade_id])
  end

  def mass_input

 #use this to create the inserts (to_do) 
    datos = JSON.parse(params[:form_data])
  end
```

And I'm creating a massive input for students using Handsontable. My problem is I dont know how to pass the grade id (or if I need to pass it) in coffee code.

I tried with this new routes (if I dont create GET route throws error even  selecting POST in the ajax part.

```
  get 'students/mass_input', to: 'students#mass_input'
  post 'students/mass_input', to: 'students#mass_input', as: 'mass_input'
```

coffee button code

```
  $('#stu_mass_input').on 'click', (e) ->
    form_data = { 
      mass_students: mass_students.getData(), 
    }
    $.ajax
      method: 'POST',
      data: { form_data: JSON.stringify(form_data)},
      url: '/students/mass_input'
```

I get the error **Couldn't find Grade with 'id'=** (expectable, im not giving the grade id in the URL)

I tried several ways of nesting this mass_input routes but I get the error **"No student with 'id = mass_input' "**

thanks guys

***edit : Button is INSIDE a grade, so I have to pass the current url grade id for this mass students input***

Comment: Can please post the controller code and stack traces for the errors you received. With the updated routes, there is no need to embed the grade id in the url.

Comment: Thanks for answering , I posted the controller code and this is the stack trace :app/controllers/students_controller.rb:85:in `set_grade'

Comment: did you try to run `rake routes|grep students` in the terminal and see what kind of urls are generated for those routes?

Comment: In the form, have you put `grade_id`? what's the parameter name of `grade_id`?

Comment: grade_id comes from the URL as they are nested resources ocalhost:3000/schools/4/grades/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing because your before filter `set_grade` is expecting a parameter grade_id. You can pass this as a query parameter in the url to which you send the ajax request.

Alternatively, if your mass creation does not actually require grade to be present, you can skip the before filter for this action:

```
before_action :set_grade, except: [:mass_input]
```

---

Assuming you have the grade_id in the parent page, you can pass it to javascript using a generated script tag:

In action:

```
@grade_id = params[:id]
```

In your erb template:

```
<script>
  REGISTRY = { grade_id: "<%= @grade_id %>" }
</script>
```

In coffee, should be included after the script tag above:

```
  $('#stu_mass_input').on 'click', (e) ->
    form_data = { 
      mass_students: mass_students.getData(), 
    }
    $.ajax
      method: 'POST',
      data: { form_data: JSON.stringify(form_data)},
      url: "/students/mass_input?grade_id=#{REGISTRY.grade_id}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried without setting grade, but I need grade id to assign the student to the correct grade, how can I pass the id from URL ?

the URL from I'm pressing the button already have the grade_id

http://localhost:3000/schools/4/grades/2

Comment: I could get the grade_id , but now I cant assign the grade to a student ( grade.students << student ) without overriding my create method , maybe its a scoping problem but I cant figure out why .. BTW your answer is the first step to solve the problem. THANKS